# Does the new "Siri Page," on iOS 9, work with the iPhone 4s?

Tags: bug, ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s which has the new iOS 9 downloaded on to it. The only problem is, is that the left most page, the one with predictive Siri, is not present. Is there some setting that is off, or is that feature just not available for the 4s?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that feature is only present on iPhone 5 and later.